# Why out heap of memory, why last item in array don't step + 0.1?

Tags: javascript

Why out heap of memory, why last item in array don't step + 0.1?

```
const array = [];
const step = 0.1;
do {
    const item = array[array.length - 1] ? array[array.length - 1] : 0;
    array.push(item + step);
} while (array[array.length - 1] !== 100);
```

Comment: Use `while (array[array.length - 1] < 100)` because you will not get EXACTLY 100, due to rounding.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Due to floating point errors, anyway; or a lack of rounding.  `0.1` cannot be represented exactly in binary, so floating point errors will acrue.

Comment: ???? 
array = [0]
array.push(0 + 0.1)
console.log(array[array.length - 1]) // 0.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @ДаниилСоловьев And `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1` != `0.3` because of how floating point values works.

Comment: @Amy you mean 0.1 not number??

Comment: @ДаниилСоловьев What?  Of course `0.1` is a number.

Comment: @Amy 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 != 0.3 why??  :))))))))))))))))

Comment: @ДаниилСоловьев Read the link ASDFGerte posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use less-than instead of not-equal-to e.g. `while (array[array.length - 1] < 100)`, because you will not get EXACTLY 100, due to the nature of floating-point arithmetic.

See the output from the program below.

```js
console.log(generateSequence(0, 100, 0.1));

function generateSequence(start, end, step) {
  let result = [];
  do {
    const prev = result[result.length - 1] ? result[result.length - 1] : 0;
    result.push(prev + step);
  } while (result[result.length - 1] < 100);
  return result;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

#### Alternatively

You can increase the magnitude of the number, floor it, then divide it.

As you can see it works for multiple precisions.

```js
console.log(generateSequence(0, 100, 1).join(', '));
console.log(generateSequence(0, 100, 10).join(', '));
console.log(generateSequence(0, 100, 0.1).join(', '));
console.log(generateSequence(0, 100, 0.025).join(', '));

function generateSequence(start, end, step) {
  let result = [],
      trueEnd = end / step,
      precision = step < 1 ? 1 / step : 1,
      p2 = Math.pow(precision, 2);
  for (let i = 0; i < trueEnd; i++) {
    result.push(Math.floor(i * precision) / p2);
  }
  return result;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: my task was push to array from 0 to 100, when step must be 0.1

Comment: @ДаниилСоловьев See the updated code at the bottom.